# IWinHttpRequest fails with status code 407 even after SetCredentials for "www.google.com"

Tags: winhttp, winhttprequest

My system Browser (IE) is proxy authenticated. I tried to download "www.google.com" using
IWinHttpRequest it fails with status code 407 ( Need Proxy Authentication ) even after setting the user name and password using SetCredentials(...) for "www.google.com".  The response text contains "cache access denied".  How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

SetCredentials should be called twice as follows

```
hr = pIWinHttpRequest->SetCredentials(bstrUserName, bstrPassword, HTTPREQUEST_SETCREDENTIALS_FOR_SERVER);
hr = pIWinHttpRequest->SetCredentials(bstrUserName, bstrPassword, HTTPREQUEST_SETCREDENTIALS_FOR_PROXY);
```

before called "Send"